# Blackerry Playbook camera not supported in release build

Tags: flash, build, air, camera, blackberry-playbook

I am developing an application for iOS/Android/BB Tablet that requires the use of the camera. During the development, I have tested the functionality of the camera multiple times with debug builds of the app on multiple devices, including the Blackberry Playbook. I recently did a signed release build and noticed that any time I call CameraUI.isSupported, it no longer works on the Playbook, even though the release build works just fine for 5+ other devices.

I have tried building the project with AIR 2.6, 2.7, and 3.1 with BB Tablet SDKs 1.1.1 and 2.0 beta. I am installing the signed app via the command line using the BB SDK deploy tools. My settings in Flash builder (Build Packaging -> BB Tablet OS -> Permissions) have "use_camera" checked. The same settings are reflected properly in my blackberry-tablet.xml. Looking at the application permissions on the Playbook after installing the app shows use of the camera enabled so I don't think it is a permissions issue.

Comment: For anyone else having this issue, I managed to resolve it by changing the <permission> tag in blackberry-tablet.xml to <action>. It turns out the permissions tags are old and are used by the IDE whereas action tags are used by the packager. You will probably need to just duplicate the tags - 1 for each permission using the permission tag and one using the action tag. Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Hi Colin. I found this earlier and had the same problem except it was in the debug version and for the image gallery. Setting the allow_share permission solved it. Thanks for the info about the action tag. It sounds like I'll have to update this for the packager!